# escaping <style> tag in <head>

Tags: html, css, escaping, html-email

is it possible to escape something like this in `<head>`?

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <style type="text/css">
    table {
    width:560px
    }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">
.ReadMsgBody {width: 100%;}
.ExternalClass {width: 100%;}
</style>
```

this is for an html email and i need this to be where it is. the problem is the parser in the software sending the emails. gives out an error.

i was wondering if there's a way to "escape" it.

obviously this didn't work:

```
&lt;!--[if gte mso 9]&gt;
    &lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;
    table {
    width:560px
    }
    &lt;/style&gt;
&lt;![endif]--&gt;
&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;
.ReadMsgBody {width: 100%;}
.ExternalClass {width: 100%;}
&lt;/style&gt;
```

Comment: "the problem is the parser in the software sending the emails. gives out an error" — Whatever the solution to the problem is, it is likely to depend very much on that parser and how you are using it.

Comment: yeah it's a my problem/your problem kind of issue. i was wondering if could do something or if it's "their" problem to solve the issue.

Comment: It's throwing an error on a perfectly valid HTML comment. That sounds like a problem with the parser.